# Is it easy to test human Flicker Fusion Threshold?

Tags: human-biology, human-eye

How would you go about testing human flicker fusion threshold? Is the testable rate consistent in humans over time or volatile?

Answer (score 2):

Flicker-fusion rates are very easy to test in humans: you provide a flickering light-source, set it to flicker at different speeds, and get the people to tell you whether the light is flickering or constant. [This paper](http://physrev.physiology.org/content/32/3/349) (from 1952) achieved a flickering light by putting a rotating disc with holes in it in front of a projected light source. A more modern testing unit is demonstrated [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSYP2EUGrr0).

The human flicker-fusion rate does not appear to be a constant. In addition to being influenced by attributes of the light source (such as [its wavelength, how much the brightness changes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_fusion_threshold), etc), it also appears to be influenced by factors such as [stress](http://journals.lww.com/psychosomaticmedicine/Abstract/1947/07000/Flicker_Fusion_Frequency_as_a_Function_of_Anxiety.8.aspx) and [fatigue](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjACahUKEwiy3c73rubIAhUD5KYKHYXMCc0&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffaculty.ucr.edu%2F~aseitz%2Fpubs%2FSeitz_HumPsychopharm05.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEKVUClwXkVhTLFqWqa1JjwkLDZ2g&sig2=5Zz5bxopOdU2E85nWN4Aog) (pdf).

Comment: Great - thanks for the information. I'm mainly curious on how human flicker-fusion rate in athletes might correlate to size and/or performance. As in some players (possibly smaller) 'see' the game faster. But this seems tough to test in a non-biased way. It seems like testing reflexes/reaction times would be more appropriate.